# Does a full transaction log cause a rollback?

Tags: sql-server, transaction-log

Will a transaction that is trying to write something into the transaction log be rolled back if the transaction log is full?

Answer (score 2):

Yes but it will be the rollback which actually causes the log to become physically full.

As a transaction generates log records, it will also reserve space in the log for any records required required to rollback. With 20MB of log space remaining and a hypothetical transaction that generates 10MB of log records, you would receive the log full error with 10MB still free and the rollback would then consume that 10MB.

Comment: Nice info on the log space reservation for rollback.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

The log entry is needed to rollback (or server fail etc) so all the changes *must* be recorded.

Answer (score 0):

YES. check this KB http://support.microsoft.com/kb/110139

Comment: That KB article is for SQL Server 6.5, 6.0, and 4.21. It may still be correct and relevant to some degree, but I wouldn't bet any production databases on it.

Answer (score 0):

In sybase you have ["abort tran on log full" db_option](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966478.aspx) to choose what to do.

In SQL Server you can't really choose, the rollback is made.